How do I iterate through table rows in Python?

How would I loop through HTML Table Rows in Python? Just to let y'all know, I am working on the website: https://schools.texastribune.org/districts/. What I'm trying to do is click each link in the table body (?) and extract the total number of students: 
What I have so far:
response = requests.get("https://schools.texastribune.org/districts/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

data = []

for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'table table-striped'}):

    response = requests.get(a.get('href'))
    asoup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    data.append({
        'url': a.get('href'),
        'title': a.h2.get_text(strip=True),
        'content': asoup.article.get_text(strip=True)
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)

This is my first ever time web scraping something.

What are you expecting to find with match.find('ul')? There are no <ul> elements in the HTML.

The total students information you want isn't in the table. You have to follow the link in the <a> tag to get the details for that school.

What @Barmar says is quite correct in which case you may want to consider multithreading if performance is of concern

You should not have class_="td" when finding the <td> elements, they don't have any class.
There's no <ul> elements in the table, so view = match.find('ul',class_="tr") won't find anything. You need to find the <a> element, gets its href, and load that to get the total students.
d = {}
for match in soup.find_all('td'):
    link = match.find("a")
    if link and link.href:
        school_page = requests.get("https://schools.texastribune.org" + link.href)
        school_soup = BeautifulSoup(school_page, 'lxml')
        total_div = school_soup.find("div", class_="metric", text="Total students"
        if total_div:
            amount = total_div.find("p", class_="metric-value")
            d[link.text] = amount.text

print(d)


I'm also new to Python. Thank you for this. I'll be using this as a case study for myself. Would it really be "td" and not "tbody" in the second line?

You could use tr to loop over the rows. But not tbody because there's just one of those.

You could also use for link in soup.select('td a') to go directly to the links.

I get this error on the school_page row: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

I added a check that link.href is not None.
